# QT OpenGL for Desktop required for windowing?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm a bit unsure about compiling QT 5.2.1 without OpenGL support. I always thought that OpenGL would be needed for application which wish to do graphics, but when I read the documentation there is talk about 2D on Desktop functionality as well. If I don't plan to use any graphics and just want to make use of the windowing framework of QT, do I still need that desktop suport?
Somehow this wouldn't make sense to allow it as an optional component it were required but I don't really know if it is required anyway, because I don't know what this support would be used for.

So the primary question is, if I just want to implement a regular desktop application which uses windows and widgets, I don't need to compile with OpenGL support, right?

I have used wxWidgets as my cross platform library so far, and never needed to touch OpenGL, so I would use QT in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I just want to implement a regular desktop application which uses windows and widgets, I don't need to compile with OpenGL support, right?

I think the answer is yes; although at the app level, like [this thread](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25787) specifically calls out, from Qt 5 onwards setting the graphic subsystem to raster `-graphicssystem raster` is deprecated, you can [set the window's surface type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#setSurfaceType) to `RasterSurface`, which allows rendering using raster without OpenGL support using `QBackingStore` (a non-OpenGL drawing context); [its API doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qbackingstore.html#details) confirms this. [`QWindow`'s documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#details) also briefs this.

> If I don't plan to use any graphics and just want to make use of the windowing framework of QT, do I still need that desktop suport?

Yes, if you need [QML and Qt5's QtQuick 2 render or QtGui which exclusively use OpenGL](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) and is a core part of the Qt's graphics system. No, if you can do it without any of those. This Qt 5 [Raster Window sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/rasterwindow.html) does exactly that; you can notice that the project file has no mention of OpenGL in it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it's complicated. `QtCore` will run perfectly happily without the OpenGL dependency, however with Qt5 they moved the widget system heavily towards using OpenGL(ES) for performance reasons. It's a bit difficult to find an answer on this through the Qt documentation, however if you just want to build a Qt5 application with `QtWidgets` you can specify no OpenGL on the configure statement and you'll be fine. If you wish to use `QML` then you need the OpenGL dependency to get it work, but the `QtWidget` system is now effectively done so it won't be improved any time soon.

Comment: Actually using QML is IMO required if you want to take advatnage of GUI building outside the source, right? So I guess I have to go to the hassle of figuring out how to get OpenGL support...

Comment: Yes, QML is a declarative language, precisely for seprating UI design from code. Yes, if you need QML, then you are opting in for OpenGL since it's a dependency for that.

Comment: @Devolus: you can still build a GUI with the `QtWidgets`, however it won't be as 'custom' as you can get with QML unless you're willing to build the custom elements you want yourself. I personally still use `QtWidgets` for the main UI and just build custom UI components as I need them, but it has a mildly steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL module is needed only if you want to use glWidget, for classical desktop application you don't need it.